Does measuring a quantum object collapse the wave function even if the particle is not found in the position where it was measured?
I am struggling to understand the nature of observations in quantum mechanics. My understanding is the following. Properties of quantum objects are determined by a wave function. This wave function represents the square root of the probability of finding the quantum object in a given state.
My question is, say you have an electron. The electron has some wave function defining its position. There is a 2% chance that the electron is found in position X. If I shine a light, at position X, and the electron is not found there, does the electron then collapse into existence at one of the other positions defined by the wave function? If this is the case, what if the electron is extremely spread out across the universe and has a very small probability of being measured 1000 light years away or something? Could you then shine a light over there and collapse the wave function on earth?
Further, imagine a quadruple slit experiment (like the double slit but with 4 slits). What happens if you measure the electron at one of the 4 slits but not the other 3? I assume the electron collapses and you’ll just see 4 lines rather than an interference pattern. Is that the case?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The "collapse of the wave function" is a very unphysical concept: It was invented within the Copenhagen Interpretation by people who tried to make sense of Quantum Mechanics, and who probably went astray at precisely that point. The collapse is not needed for understanding quantum mechanics, and probably does more harm than good.
Anyways, what does this "collapse" mean in the first place? When you perform a measurement of some property, you set up some kind of experiment that decomposes the wave function into a set of eigenfunctions of that property. If you measure spin, you get a set of eigenfunctions that have a defined spin. If you measure location, you get an (infinite) set of eigenfunctions that have the particle in a single location and totally unknown impulse. And if you measure impulse, you get eigenfunctions that correspond to precise impulse vectors by describing an infinite planar wave.
After the measurement, you know more about the amplitudes of these different eigenfunctions, or so you think. As such, you can take out the eigenfunctions that have a vanishing amplitude, and continue with the rest. This throwing away of eigenfunctions whose eigenvalues were not the result of the measurement is what people call the collapse of the wave function. Because after that measurement, you are continuing with a "reduced" wavefunction, a wavefunction that has been projected onto a base with fewer dimensions than before. And that is also the direct answer to your question: It does not matter whether you reduce the wave function because you have measured something, or because you have not measured something, the result is the same. You set the amplitudes of some not measured eigenfunctions to zero, renormalize, and continue with the reduced wave function.
Note that this wave function collapse is purely a mathematical operation that you perform depending on the knowledge of the outcome of the experiment. However, you are a quantum object yourself. As well as the measurement aparatus. So, what actually happens (according to the math, that is) is that you become entangled with the particle you are measuring. So your own wavefunction can now be decomposed into one where you measured result A and another part where you measured result B. And the same is also true for the piece of paper where you write down the result, the people you inform of the result, the photons that hit your writing and subsequently escape to space, etc., pp., ad infinitum.
At least, that's what the math says. Obviously, this is a little hard to grasp, and probably even harder to believe, and physicists are no exception to that. As such, they came up with the Copenhagen Interpretation, blaming some kind of conscience for collapsing the wave function. In any case, we humans are venturing beyond what we can easily understand here. But I, for one, find it much easier to think about when I consider that my measurements entangle me with the state of the system which I measured, and notice that I cannot undo that entanglement because the photons that entangled me with the readout of the measurement aparatus have also entangled me with a hole lot of other particles in the room etc. so that it's impossible to bring my entangled parts back into coherence with one another. Some people call this the Many Worlds Interpretation, though I don't think of it as splitting the universe. I do not know how the universe is able to compute this, I only know that it's the least amount of non-physical assumptions. Anything beyond that is pure philosopic speculation imho, and I leave that to less science focused people than myself.

The concept which I think is really confusing me is the way the superposition behaves after a measurement which doesn’t reveal the position of the electron. We can see in the double slit experiment that the electron exists in a wave-like state until it is measured. If you measure at the slits you don’t get the interference pattern. What if you don’t find the electron though? You say you update your wave function to use 0 amplitude in the “not found” eigenstate, but does the electron continue to exist in a superposition of all the other states and interfere like in the double slit experiment?

@JeffreyBringolf Mathematically, the electron gets entangled with you at the measurement/slit. At that point, your own wave function is split into two parts, one that observes the electron, and one that does not. Because you cannot reverse this entanglement (because you can't track down all the entangled particles), the two partial wavefunctions cannot interfere with one another anymore, and in each of the two parts, the electron went only through a single slit. Thus, the electrons exhibits only the behavior of going through a single slit in either case.

Okay that makes sense. I guess my confusion is related to when you wrote: “As such, you can take out the eigenfunctions that have a vanishing amplitude, and continue with the rest.” To me, this implies that after a “missed” measurement, you continue to treat unmeasured positions as though they’re still in a superposition. If this is the case, wouldn’t a “triple slit” experiment still demonstrate interference in the two unmeasured slits? Is this the case?

@JeffreyBringolf Yes, precisely. If you only observe a single of three slots, and do not detect an electron, it must have gone through the remaining two. And the two wavefunctions for the remaining two slots can still interfere with one another. Mathematically, this operation is called a projection because it removes one or more of the orthogonal eigenfunctions from the base (this views wavefunctions as vectors in a vector space with those orthogonal eigenfunctions as its base), and the resulting wave function thus is of lower dimensionality as what went in.

Gotcha! That makes much more sense. Do we have any intuition on what actually occurs in the area of space where we had the "missed" measurement? For something like the Stern-Gerlach experiment it makes sense that the spin is manipulated by the magnetic field and becomes quantized, but that same intuition doesn't really work for this other type of measurement. Do we know what exactly we're physically affecting when we perform this kind of projection operation or do we just know that experimental results and the math work out?

@JeffreyBringolf The projection is not about affecting something physically, it is about updating our model of the quantum system with the newly gained information about the result of the measurement. It's the same operation that I called "throwing away of eigenfunctions" in the answer itself. "Projection" is merely the mathematical name of this operation. And it is called "projection" because it reduces the number of dimension that you need to describe the wave function. I just thought it would be a good idea to mention that term as well since it's the technical one. Sorry if it confused you.

Right, but there is something physical occurring since interference patterns will no longer be observed from the eigenstate we eliminated during the projection. For instance, in the “triple slit” experiment we spoke about, with no measurements, there would be an interference pattern caused by all three slits interfering with each other. But if we measure just one slit, like you said above, only the two non-measured slits will demonstrate an interference pattern. So there must be some physical difference between the system before and after the measurement no?

@JeffreyBringolf Yes, there is a physical difference: After the measurement (and your subsequential projection), the state of the particle is entangled with you and the things that you know. The wave function is still split into one part where you observed the particle, and one part where you didn't. The part with the observation contains you deducing a single slit interference pattern, the part without the observation contains you deducing a double slit interference pattern. These two parts won't get together anymore because you cannot undo the entanglement of the particle with your brain.

We are talking about a statistical law here. The probability of finding the particle in region $[x+\Delta x]$:
$$
P(x < X < x+\Delta x)=|\psi(X)|^2\Delta x=w
$$
This means that, after performing $N$ measurements, we find the particle about  $wN$ times in the region of interest and $(1-w)N$ times we do not find it there.
Every measurement instance collapses the wave function (with some caveats when the measuring operator commutes with the Hamiltonian), so the averaging has to be done with an ensemble of particles "prepared in identical quantum states" (see Ensemble interpretation.)

What you say is true, but I don't see how this addresses the question at all.

@TobiasFünke This probably means that you and I do not understand the question in the same way. But from your comment it is not clear where you disagree.

Yes. See my comment under the question for my understanding of OP's question. TL;DR: The question asks, in my understanding, what to do (e.g. mathematically) if a "non-measurement" happens.

@TobiasFünke I see only your comment with references to works on interpretation of QM. Ultimately, the question opens a possibility for discussing this (and whether collapse really takes place), but IMHO the OP is just beginning to study QM, and needs a basic explanation in terms of Copenhagen interpretation (which is probably what they are taught.) If you want to go beyond that - it is a good reason for writing an extended answer, and you might be better qualified for this than me... but as s criticism of my answer it seems unjust.

You write:

Properties of quantum objects are determined by a wave function.

Not exactly. The wavefunction represents the evolution of the system. Sometimes that evolution involves what is happening to all of the possible results of a measurement, e.g. - interference experiments in Section 2 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150

This wave function represents the square root of the probability of finding the quantum object in a given state.

No. The square amplitude of the wavefunction for the state in question represents the probability in circumstances where interference is negligible. During interference experiments, square amplitudes do not evolve in a way that is consistent with them being probabilities as explained in the link above.

My question is, say you have an electron. The electron has some wave function defining its position. There is a 2% chance that the electron is found in position X. If I shine a light, at position X, and the electron is not found there, does the electron then collapse into existence at one of the other positions defined by the wave function? If this is the case, what if the electron is extremely spread out across the universe and has a very small probability of being measured 1000 light years away or something? Could you then shine a light over there and collapse the wave function on earth?

A measurement is an interaction that produces a record that can be examined and copied.
According to the equations of motion of quantum theory when information is copied out of a system, interference is suppressed, this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Since interference with the other possible states is negligible after a measurement no collapse is required to explain why you see only a single outcome and collapse doesn't appear in the relevant equations. The other outcomes don't mysteriously vanish they are just dynamically isolated from you so that you can't interact with them:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
This is usually called the many worlds interpretation but it is just a result of working out the consequences of the equations of motion as one would for any other theory.  See "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch, Chapter 2 for a popular account. Many physicists dislike this conclusion for unclear reasons and insist on collapse or some other alternative to quantum theory.
What happens to an electron here if somebody in Andromeda measures it? Nothing. The relevant equations of motion are those of relativistic quantum field theories and in such theories changes propagate at the speed of light. No measurement you could do on an electron here could tell you anything about what is happening to an electron in Andromeda right now, or at any other event spacelike separated from where you're doing the measurement.

Further, imagine a quadruple slit experiment (like the double slit but with 4 slits). What happens if you measure the electron at one of the 4 slits but not the other 3? I assume the electron collapses and you’ll just see 4 lines rather than an interference pattern. Is that the case?

No. You would see a 3 slit pattern. You have blocked the electron from the fourth slit so the electron wavefunction will arrive at any given point on the screen from the other three slits.
Attempts have been made to modify quantum equations of motion to include collapse
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
Such theories can't currently reproduce the results predicted by relativistic quantum theories, i.e. - almost all actual experimental results:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Collapse is also incompatible with a lot of real measurements such as repeated, continuous and unsharp measurements:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973

"Many physicists dislike this conclusion for unclear reasons..."   If you consider Schroedinger's equation as a means to predict the possible outcomes of a measurement and you know that there will be only one outcome, why would you attribute any reality to the outcomes that were not found?

In general there will be more than one outcome and for each outcome there will be a version of the observer or measuring instrument that sees the outcome. The explanation for interference and entanglement experiments involves the existence of more than one version of each system and for entanglement experiments this includes macroscopic systems like measurement devices https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
