What are some experimental facts/logical reasons to dismiss arguments for consciousness collapse interpretations?
Let's start by defining consciousness collapse interpretation as the claim that, when we a person performs a measurement of a quantum system, a definite outcome is realised only when the person witnesses the outcome of the experiment in their experience of the world.
Now, there are two arguments which seem to support this claim :
1. The Schrodinger equation : We suppose that the measurement device itself is a system of particles that obey quantum mechanics. Then a consequence of the Schrodinger equation is that the measurement device goes into a superposition after the measurement. Then if we model the experimenter's brain as a quantum system, it subsequently also goes into a superposition upon interaction with the previous system. And lastly, the experimenter gets a subjective experience in which a definite outcome is observed, which is something we empirically know from our experience.
This argument seems to imply that a definite outcome is obtained at the moment of subjective experience.
Remark This argument leads to two interpretations : Relational Collapse and Many Worlds, depending on whether or not we believe that other outcomes are also realised in other worlds.
I don't want counter-arguments that distinguish between Many Worlds and Relational Interpretation. I only need counter-arguments against the above description in point 1., that is common to both Relational-Interpretation and Many Worlds.
2. The time- direction of quantisation: To quantise a field theory, we need to pick spacetime foliations or choose a time direction. This is true even for quantum Euclidean field theories, in which there is no distinction between space and time at the classical level, but there needs to be a distinguished time direction in the quantum theory. This is the direction in which the wavefunction undergoes unitary evolution.
Now, from empirical evidence, we know that the direction of unitary evolution that quantisation picks is the same as the direction in which we experience time in our subjective experience. This seems to give circumstantial evidence about a link between quantum mechanics and consciousness.
What are the experimental facts/logical arguments that help eliminate these arguments about a link between quantum mechanics and subjective experience?
P.S. I need experimental facts/logical arguments against the claim that, from the perspective of a human experimenter, the collapse happens at the moment of experience. I don't want arguments against the claim that only human experience can trigger collapse, as there are interpretations (MWI/Relational) in which this is a special instance of more general notions of collapse.

'This seems to give circumstantial evidence ' Correlation is not causation.

@my2cts I want to explain away that evidence as something that is to be expected, something follows from known principles that don't directly link QM and subjective experience

'a definite outcome is realised only when the person witnesses the outcome of the experiment' This argument is perfectly circular, extraordinarly superficial and untestable. For how could you know what came out of the experiments that no conscious being observed? Is it enough to just think about these or is there an unobserved part of the universe still in a precollapse state? Oops there it goes.

@my2cts I've written the premises for that conclusion above. It follows from modeling the measurement device and the brain according to the Schrodinger equation. If there are experiment facts/logical reasons to not believe this, that would be a great answer.

Does an extragalactic amoebe count as a conscient observer? It is this kind of question that pops up in such a debate.

"a definite outcome is realised only when the person witnesses the outcome of the experiment" - at least two big problems with this hypothesis. (1) Arbitrariness - why a person ? Why not a dog or an ant or an alien or a photo ? (2) Vagueness - when exactly does a person witness or experience anything ? The time lag from initial sensation to conscious awareness is certainly of the order of tenths of a second, which is a long time in particle physics.

The Schrödinger equation does not support the concept of collapse.

I don't understand the gist of your arguments. To me they state that because what we experience empirically is the same thing as what QM predicts, then consciousness has something to do with QM. How can this not apply to physics as a whole? And since physics is indeed the product of our (collective) consciousness, it amounts to a trivial observation. What am I missing?

@my2cts argument 1. does not pin down a specific interpretation, but a family of interpretations each of which define "observer" differently. There are many interpretations like MWI and Relational Interpretation that are consistent with it. In the former, any macroscopic system can act as an observer and human consciousness is a special case of those. . I want experimental facts/logical arguments against arguments 1 in general, which would apply to this entire family of interpretations

@gandalf61 argument 1. does not pin down a specific interpretation, but a family of interpretations each of which define "observer" differently. There are many interpretations like MWI and Relational Interpretation that are consistent with it. In the former, any macroscopic system can act as an observer and human consciousness is a special case of those. I want experimental facts/logical arguments against arguments 1 in general, which would apply to this entire family of interpretations

@StéphaneRollandin thanks. I think that that is a great reason to discard the second argument in this post. But the first argument is specific to certain interpretations of quantum mechanics (like MWI), and it does not apply to other interpretations as well as to classical mechanics

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/826484/does-measuring-a-quantum-object-collapse-the-wave-function-even-if-the-particle/826509#826509

@RyderRude 'I want experimental facts/logical arguments against arguments 1 in general' Argument 1 is simply not valid. Our brain does not 'go into superposition'. It is not a coherent system.

@my2cts this is wrong. Whether or not decoherence forbids macroscopic superposition depends on the interpretation.  e.g. in MWI, the brain does go into a superposition

@RyderRude Rude indeed. Of course, MWI is phantasy.

@my2cts again, I'm not advocating for MWI or any of the other interpretations that follow from argument 1. I just need logical/experimental facts that oppose argument 1. Decoherence is not one of those facts, as decoherence is an interpretation independent fact. Also, maybe you will find this other question to be better phrased https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/830807/what-mathematical-results-support-the-idea-that-the-wavefunction-does-not-evolve

The obvious answer is that the Universe evolved according to the laws of physics long before any humans were around to influence interactions between its constituent parts by observing their outcomes.

I need experimental facts/logical arguments against the claim that, from the perspective of a human experimenter, the collapse happens at the moment of experience. I don't want arguments against the claim that only human experience can trigger collapse, as there are interpretations (MWI/Relational) in which this is a special instance of more general notions of collapse.

Well think for two minutes!

Imagine an experiment the result of which either triggers an explosion in chile or in Birkenhead. Are you saying neither explosion happens until some physicist is aware of the result???

I am saying that neither explosion happens from the perspective of a human until that human is aware of that result. This follows from the argument using Schrodinger equation. i am not saying that neither explosion happens in some general sense (e.g. the explosions still happen wrt other objects in Relational or Many Worlds interpretation. These objects don't need to be alive)

Also, I'm not advocating that this is true. I have other arguments that  oppose this. I just just need to disprove for these two arguments which support it.

The arguments are nonsense. Why do you need evidence to refute them? The direction of time is ‘picked out’ by my watch, the movement of a glacier, a tv program and every other physical process we know of, so is that circumstantial evidence for them all being linked linked to consciousness?

Maybe you will find this other question to be better phrased https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/830807/what-mathematical-results-support-the-idea-that-the-wavefunction-does-not-evolve
